# NSString category method not called after creating NSSavePanel

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I have [a simple Cocoa application](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21723817/TrimWhitespace.zip) (39 KB zipped) that consists of an application delegate (`AppDelegate`) and an `NSString` category (and a default window that does nothing).

In its `init` method, the `AppDelegate` creates an `NSSavePanel`. Before and after it does this, it logs the length of a string trimmed of whitespace and newlines by an `NSString` category method: `stringByTrimmingWhitespace`.

The string consists of whitespace and newline characters. My category method should trim all of these characters, resulting in a 0-length string.

Before the `NSSavePanel` is created, my `stringByTrimmingWhitespace` method is called and returns a 0-length string, as expected. After the `NSSavePanel` is created, my `stringByTrimmingWhitespace` method does not appear to be called, and whatever method is called does not trim newlines. However, a different `NSString` category method that does exactly the same thing—`stringByTrimmingWhitespaceAndNewlines`—is called and works as expected.

I have absolutely no idea what is causing my `stringByTrimmingWhitespace` to not be called or how to fix it (besides renaming it, which is what I’ve done). I’m also concerned that other category methods on other classes may be getting trashed. Does anyone know what’s happening here?

Comment: I checked this out, and I hope someone can answer it, because I have no idea. Even if stringByTrimmingWhitespace were some private reserved name, it wouldn't explain why it works before showing the panel but not after. Weird, really weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems as though `NSSavePanel` is loading a category on NSString for its own use, with a method whose name conflicts with your `-[NSString(TurnerAdditions) stringByTrimmingWhitespace]` method. You can verify with this code:

```
NSString *foo = @"!";
NSLog(@"Responds to '-stringByTrimmingWhitespace': %@", [foo respondsToSelector:@selector(stringByTrimmingWhitespace)] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
NSLog(@"Responds to '-stringByTrimmingWhitespace': %@", [foo respondsToSelector:@selector(stringByTrimmingWhitespace)] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Why it doesn't behave the same as yours is somewhat strange (edit: no it's not, see @rdelmar's comment).

You should ***always*** be prefixing the method names in your categories, specifically for instances like this. Cocoa naming conventions are fairly explicit, which makes it very likely to have name conflicts. Because of the way categories are handled (e.g. they can be loaded in the middle of an app's execution without your knowledge) it's difficult/impossible for the compiler to provide conflict errors.

Comment: It's not strange that it behaves differently -- the NSPanel method does what its name implies, whereas the OP's method also removes line breaks. +1 for solving this mystery.

Comment: Ahh, you're absolutely right. I totally glossed over what the actual input string was.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the analysis and the code. This makes perfect sense now. It seems like an odd decision on Apple’s part not to prefix their method with an underscore—there are [a few frameworks](http://www.google.com/search?q=NSString+stringByTrimmingWhitespace) with this category method that will also be overwritten when `NSSavePanel` is loaded—but those will still work because they don’t also remove newlines. Live and learn!